# Start R as different user

Tags: r, ubuntu, hadoop

While creating Hadoop environment on my PC I have created a user, hduser. Upon this Hadoop environment I have installed RHadoop. But now I face some permission issues when I start R and try to do some Hadoop operations, because I created the Hadoop environment for the hduser. Is it possible to control as which user I run R? How can I start it as hduser? I tried to login as hduser in order to install and start R there, but this didn't work as I was not able to login as hduser.

P.S.: I am pretty new to Ubuntu and Hadoop

Comment: My guess is that this belongs to askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
runuser -l hduser 'R'
```

or

```
su - hduser
```

This is not going to work unless you are the superuser.

Comment: If you want to give some usere permission to run a specific command as another user use the sudoers file. And allow them to run it using the sudo command

Comment: @MeirMaor I don't see what that has to do with the OP's question. He already presumably has superuser privileges. He just wants to be able to run a process as another user, for whom passwd access is not set up.

Comment: It was unclear which users need this this access. Regardless, the post mentions ubuntu which suggests he doesn't use a root login but rather uses sudo to become root. Adding a specific sudo can allow running this without typing a password.

Comment: @MeirMaor That would still not mean running the process as `hduser` which is what the OP wants, presumably to limit access. Running Hadoop processes as superuser is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks fg nu! But unfortunately this doens't help me. `runuser` is unknown command. When I try to start RStudio from the command line as hduser I get the message: `No protocol specified
rstudio: cannot connect to X server :0
` I will aks the same question on askubuntu